# Increment field in Yii using updateAll()

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

Good day!
How to using **updateAll()** to make all records increment field on one?

```
Players::model()->updateAll(array('contract' => 5), 'contract < 5');
```

How do **contract = contract + 1**, not **'contract' => 5**?

There http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#saveCounters-detail, but it is only for one record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$model->updateAll()` can't do this, you should do this:

```
$model->updateCounters(array("contract"=>"1"),"contract < 5");
```

this, increments `contract` field on one, in every record that `contract < 5`